# Which Platform to follow!

Tags: open-source, ide, c

I am trying to make a puzzle solving program utilizing Dijkstra in Arduino IDE. Turns out i can no more work on it(IDE), because every time i need arduino to connect it and run my program. So i want to change my platform. I know only to code in c++. Well, i am well accustomed to arduino ide functions so it seems difficult to get on making original c codes.Please could you recommend me a easy platform to code in c as available in arduino IDE but no need to connect arduino to run the program.

Plus i wish to test it on different sets of Matrix puzzles. i am unable to find a place where i could get large binary maze, every online program i encountered generated a image of the puzzle rather then in a binary matrix.

I am a armature and
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I, finally it seem's that you just need another IDE to write code in C/C++. [Visual Studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) is easy to use, and free!

Comment: Thanks for the advice,but i just found out about processing IDE. Well, could you help me out with the bin. maze part.

Comment: I don't think that Visual Studio Code knows about the Arduino software libraries, so it won't work out of the box. However, it looks like this might help you https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino

Comment: He could use the free version: Visual Studio Community